# Save the list of results of a term frequency document matrix

Tags: r

Here a dummy text:

```
df$text <- c("This is just a text in order to test the term frequency matrix save result process. I would like to save all results after the term frequency process into one dataframe...")
```

The text mining process

```
library(tm)
corpusD <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))
myStopwords <- c("would", "e g")
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, tolower)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeNumbers)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeWords, myStopwords)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, stripWhitespace)
matrixD <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpusD)
```

I would like to take all results from the last step TermDocumentMatrix into a dataframe like:

```
term frequency
frequency 2
matrix 1
```

but if I try to save the results into a csv file the only give the frequency not the term. Any idea how is it possible to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `data.frame` before you save.

```
df1 <- c("This is just a text in order to test the term frequency matrix save result process. I would like to save all results after the term frequency process into one dataframe...")

library(tm)
corpusD <- Corpus(VectorSource(df1))
myStopwords <- c("would", "e g")
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, tolower)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeNumbers)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeWords, myStopwords)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, stripWhitespace)
matrixD <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpusD)

res <- data.frame(term=rownames(as.matrix(matrixD)),frequency=rowSums(as.matrix(matrixD))) 
row.names(res)<-NULL

write.csv(res,"c:/temp/tm.csv")

        term frequency
1  dataframe         1
2  frequency         2
3       just         1
4       like         1
5     matrix         1
6        one         1
7      order         1
8    process         2
9     result         1
10   results         1
11      save         2
12      term         2
13      test         1
14      text         1
```